# Activity Log is something wrong

Tags: datatable, google-bigquery, activitylog

To Whom It May Concern,

My "Activity" log is something wrong. Would you please tell me what happend and how to resolvve this problem.

Please confirm the attaced file.
The activity logs show "Failed:Create table", but in the text showed "has created".
What did it mean? Is this sucsessfully?

Confirming the data table, I thought data table is created sucsessfully.

Regards,
Yuka
[BigQuery Activity log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsk4y.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunately a problem when Firebase exporting data to BigQuery, it tries to create a table (which may have existed) first and receives this "Failed:create table" when the table actually exists. You may fire a bug to Firebase.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
How should I check the correct log? Does running SQL the only way to check the current status on BigQuery?